# How to show that Peano axioms prove that if $\varphi$ defines a non-empty set, then it has a least element?

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

> Show the following statement in PA
>
> $\forall v_1\dotso\forall v_k\,(\exists v_0\,\varphi\to\exists v_0(\varphi\wedge\forall v_{k+1}<v_0\,\neg\varphi^{v_0}_{v_{k+1}}))$
>
> With $v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are free variables in $\varphi$

Hello,
I want to proof this in PA, but I do not know how to start.
I already showed in PA, that the addition is commutative and associative.

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with addition being commutative and associative. Except, perhaps, that both proofs use induction.

If you are familiar with the usual proof that induction is equivalent to the well-ordering principle of the natural numbers, this is just the internalization of this proof. If $\varphi$ defines a set, then if it is non-empty, it must have a least element.

If $0$ satisfies $\varphi$, then we are done, as $0$ is the minimum. Now show that if no $y\leq x$ satisfies $\varphi$, then either this means that $S(x)$ satisfies $\varphi$, or by the appropriate induction axiom *no* $x$ satisfies $\varphi$.

Comment: Yes, I did not think that the results of associativity and commutativity are important here, but I wanted to give this inside. We have not proofed, that induction is equivalent to the well-ordering principle yet. I will try to follow your hint, and show my results later.

Comment: The proof I mentioned about the well-ordering principle, is generally given in the first couple of weeks of undergrad, in discrete mathematics. Long before talking about the Peano axioms, first order logic, proofs, or the likes of which.

Comment: The result that every nonempty set of natural numbers, has a least element is known. We just did not proof it in the lecutre where this task comes from.

Comment: I didn't expect you to. I said that it is similar to the same proof. The same proof that you have probably seen in discrete mathematics in your freshman year. Much like how many other proofs of this vein are just internalization of proofs that you have seen previously in your studies.